# Watch/Listen change to google drive spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

After uch effort I was able to auth myself with google drive, get list of files, GET the file I want. Now want to be able to capture the changes in the google document data, thus know row and column number where change happens.

Get a feeling my answer lies here https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/handle-events#event_bubbling. New to Javascript, not sure how to get the exact row/column of changes to spreadsheet.

Changes in this document will be addition of new row.

Answer (score 1):

google spreadsheet is not built on top of the drive-realtime-API so you cannot use the listeners functionality of the latter to get notified of changes to documents of the former.